# What was the first recorded instance of burning a city or village in war?

Tags: ancient-history, warfare, records

I'm curious what the first recorded instance of a military putting a city or village to the torch.

Certainly, war predates history, as does the tactic of destroying a dwelling, but I'm focused on when the first recorded instance was...

I think I would include a pre-history event IF there were strong archaeological proofs, solid dates... etc.

Comment: The Fall of Troy?   ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "solid dates"? I doubt you would find anything solid in pre-history.

Answer (score 10):

The oldest I know of is the destruction of [Hamoukar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamoukar) in Syria. In 2005, archaeologists reported finding "collapsed mud-brick walls that had undergone heavy bombardment and ensuing fire" dating to around 3500 B.C. You can read more about the discovery [here](http://www-news.uchicago.edu/citations/05/051216.hamoukar-nyt.html).